# Killing Entropy : the first byte

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

## The first byte

2am. Of course, I'm the only one left in the open space. Stupid "last minute functionality for tomorrow please Greg"... I hit $<$Enter$>$ : compilation started. Well. I have a few minutes now, time for a coffee...

Or time to check Steven's desktop. The guy has been missing for, like, a week. Nobody knows where he went, why, or if he's in any sort of trouble. I only remember he left in the middle of the afternoon, with a weird face, and never came back. Two days ago, I noticed his computer was still on, only the screen was shut down.

Nobody's here, right ? Well, I'm gonna have a look. Just a look. I get up and approach his desktop. Among two unsolved Rubik’s Cube, food stains on scribbled paper and a dozen of E.T. and Elliot plastic miniatures (man, this is an obsession!), I reach for the power switch.

When the pixels suddenly lit up, I knew I was looking at what Steven saw right before his one-way travel from office to God knows where.

[image: Steven's Computer]

Just next to the screen, a sticky note :

[image: The note]

Perplexed, I stay in front of the screen a few minutes, without moving. I forget about the program that must have finished compiling. I forget about everything else than what I'm seeing right now, and with only these informations, I get back to my desk.

10 minutes later, I know a bit more about Steven's agenda : I know what happened just when he left office. And you, do you ?

**General hint :**

> This puzzle is less about cryptography and more about doing real stuff outside SE.

**Specific hints (you'll know when you need it) :** 
1 :

> I've already seen Steven typing his password. He used the numpad only.

2:

> Where was he when he created this password ?

3:

> Who was waiting for Steven when he left ?

Note :
*This investigation is the first of a series. Once someone figured out, the stories will go on with new challenges, under the "Killing Entropy" licence.*

**EDIT :**  Just before I left Steven's computer, I noticed the popping sound of an incoming mail.

Comment: Another good puzzle! +1 Just a note - Make sure you release the hints only if solvers are stuck. Happy Puzzling!

Comment: Thanks Techidiot ! I always feel insecure about my puzzles being actually totally unsolvable, and ppl not even trying. Well, I let the hints this time, and I continue learning for the next iteration of Killing Entropy.

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer. Adding stuff as soon as I find them.

First step:

> http://pastebin.com/6ur9j7ef
>  from the sticky note and the pastebin tab open on the image
>  This is made from Steven's accoun: http://pastebin.com/u/StevenLocksten
>  On his profile you can find this paste: http://pastebin.com/9Vs526Wu
>  Who are you Larry?

To be continued...

EDIT: I have other stuff to do and it will be bed time in a hour or so, so no solution from me for today.

Comment: Nice :) To be continued indeed ;)

Comment: Ok maybe I posted this too soon :\

Comment: No, an evolving partial answer is the way to make everyone progress on the puzzle :) Keep digging, and don't forget to talk about your unsuccessful attempts too :)

Comment: [narration addedum] Just before I left Steven's computer, I noticed the popping sound of an incoming mail.

Answer (score 4):

related to the computer screen:

> The first thing I notice is the number of bytes in the exe: 1729. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1729_(number)), it is "the smallest number expressible as the sum of two **cubes** in two different ways."
>
>  There happens to be two unsolved **Rubik’s Cubes** on his desk. Since his password are numbers only (from hint 1), it might be related to 1729 and Rubik’s Cubes somehow? Although I have no idea what the password is for at the moment.

related to the mail?:

> Here is something weird I've found. Log in to Steven's pastebin account. Go to "my settings", then go to "change profile". Here we see an email address stevenlocksten@mailinator.com. Now go to [Mailinator](https://www.mailinator.com/) and enter stevenlocksten. The mailbox is currently empty.
>
>  HOWEVER, when I checked the mailbox this afternoon, there were 3 mails of the same title and content in the mailbox. I didn't copy it down, but it was something about "Thank you for your last visit. You can use your key and sequence at any time." The mail is from "JLB @ LoB."
>
>  This could be referring to [The Library of Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Library_of_Babel), a short story written by Jorge Luis Borges. This is consistent with the library mentioned in the "direction" paste. Now go to the website [Library of Babel](https://libraryofbabel.info/). You can use the key found in the private paste as a hexagonal chamber name to find a specific hexagonal chamber.
>
>  (contributed by Techidiot and Logan) Use the OEIS A001047 series: 0, 1, 5, 19, 65. Ignore the first 0 and use the rest of the numbers in order as wall, shelf, volume, and page number. We find the following passage:
>
>  "looking for something, arent you. well it must be important for you to dig here. hope you arent looking for sense, because in this place, everything has been written already. everything ever said, every love or hate words. your future. your past. your death. the best thing youll ever write is already sitting here, somewhere. a glitch in entropy. entropy. thats why youre here. the key is in the size. when you figure out, youll know what to do."
>
>  Size is referring to the size of the exe (1729, as explained in the first section)?

---

Confirmed as irrelevant by OP

> I find the *\$10 to greg* line suspicious. If the money was returned to Greg, it should have been removed from the todo list. If it has not been returned, if I were Greg, I would be worried about whether I'm getting my \$10 back... The \$10 should have been mentioned in the story, but it was not.
>
>  Conclusion: a clue?

Comment: 1729 - Look up Ramanujan!

Comment: Greg isn't worried about his 10$. Everything related to the *.exe is important. What is the password for ?

Comment: [narration addedum] Just before I left Steven's computer, I noticed the popping sound of an incoming mail.

Comment: You found one crucial clue up there !

Comment: Going to libraryofbabel.info with that key, then using OEIS A001047 (without the first zero) for the wall, shelf, volume, and page numbers, gives:
"looking for something, arent you. well it must be important for you to dig here. hope you arent looking for sense, because in this place, everything has been written already. everything ever said, every love or hate words. your future. your past. your death. the best thing youll ever write is already sitting here, somewhere. a glitch in entropy.    entropy. thats why youre here. the key is in the size. when you figure out, youll know what to do."

Comment: It seems the mail box is empty again.

Comment: [author speaking] Important stuff have been extracted from the mailbox already, however, people deleting mail wasn't something I prepared for. My strategy was to keep sending it from time to time so everybody gets a chance to read, hoping someone would anyhow make it public as a partial answer. Tis has been sent again.

Comment: @LilianDelaveau We need to get details from that email still?

Comment: @LeppyR64 Nope, everything is now on this page. You just have to connect the clues. If you really look at the question, and eventually hint, and eventually some puzzlers comments, you'll soon find :)

Answer (score 3):

As already discovered by FrodCube

> The pastebin link points to the following text
>  weekly TODO:
>  - 10$ to greg
>  - talk to boss about last clients stupid request
>  - buy keyboard
>  - call samantha 4 dinner
>  - check the code from K_E.exe (in private pastes)
>  - debug whole narwhal project (ask intern?)
>
>
>  Also another link points to the following text -
>  *Hey Larry, stop stalking my pastes.*
>
>
>  There are other files in the archives as well which I think are private and not related to the puzzle.

Other thoughts

> The WIkipedia page shows "sécurise" also the command prompt shows French language which means he was accessing the French version of Wikipedia and is in France. And the [Project Narwhal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Narwhal) is the name of a computer program according to Wikipedia. Need to check if there is any relation between France and Project Narwhal. Also, Larry reminds me of [Larry Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Page) :)
>
>  Greg tells us that the last time Steven was seen was during the afternoon. So, if we check the schedule we can come up with following conclusions -
>  A. Either he was caught into an argument with his boss
>  B. Samantha cancelled the dinner
>  C. He didn't found the keyboard he was looking for.
>
>  There is obviously a $10 for Greg which we are not sure whether it was returned or not.

Next step

> Leppy found the password [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/49216/30887) as 1982. Logging into the account provides couple of important things - 
>
>
>   **KEY**
>  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
>
>
>  **DIRECTIONS**
>  he said i go to the library with the key
>  he said directions are A,0,0,1,0,4,7. what kind of directions are that ?
>  he also said to forget about the zero.
>
>  ???
>
>  So, we might to see what A1047 gives.
>  Some random googling gave the following things -
>
>  [UK Road A1047](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:UK_road_A1047.PNG)
>  And [Gerald_Ford_Library](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ford_A1047_NLGRF_photo_contact_sheet_(1974-09-26)(Gerald_Ford_Library).jpg) which is a clue I guess.
>
>  Or the [OEIS A001047 series](http://oeis.org/search?q=A001047&language=english&go=Search) - 0, 1, 5, 19, 65, 211, 665, 2059, 6305, 19171, 58025, 175099, 527345

Another find

> This could either me irrelevant or a clue but we have an email in the account as well. Though its a standard mail from the website, we may need it so I will paste it here -
>
>  Hello StevenLocksten,
>
>  Good to see that you have decided to join our community!
>
>  We like to remind you that our website is mobile friendly, so you can create, edit and delete pastes on your phone or tablet too.
>
>  You currently have a FREE account, but we also offer far superior PRO accounts.
>
>  Being a PRO member unlocks many cool features, and removes all advertisements from the website.
>
>  You can follow us on Facebook and Twitter.
>
>  Kind regards,
>
>  The Pastebin Team
>
>
>  Again, may not be relevant, but worth nothing, taking first letter of the n'th word in the above email with the obtained pattern we get **TITE**

Comment: For the French related thoughts, I'll have to be a little meta : I couldn't configure everything I wanted on the VM for this series, so it is in French because of external reason. Very argumented however, you Sherlock. But the clues you discovered on this topic are actually to prove I'm French ^^

Comment: Are you on some mission? ;)  I don't see any other visible clues yet. Also, can you specify in your question exactly what we need to find? *What happened?* is too broad to answer.

Comment: Well, this may be where puzzlingSE habits are hard to mix with what I want to do. "What happened ?" will be the right question at the end of the path. I understand I could formulate things better. Well, there is a serious clue in the first pastebin. A clue about what to do if I'm Greg and I want to understand things about Steven.

Comment: If there is another "Partial Answer" post, maybe copy/paste the inside from the found document could be a good idea (no pun here, no clue, just an advice ^^)

Comment: Interesting.  The commas make it un-googleable.  Remove them and try again.

Comment: @LeppyR64 I do get Gerald_Ford_Library. Need to check what that means.

Comment: I was thinking more along this line... https://oeis.org/A001047  But I don't know where to go from there.  (Ignore the first term, zero)

Comment: May be take that pattern as enumerations? Let me check how far I can go

Comment: I see nothing- **D 2 7 2 W 3** this is what I got @LeppyR64

Comment: [narration addedum] Just before I left Steven's computer, I noticed the popping sound of an incoming mail.

Comment: You found one crucial clue up there !

Comment: It's chrome that shows securise, not wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

Adding another partial because I don't like seeing you folks stuck.

> Log in to StevenLocksten's Pastebin account:
>  Username = StevenLocksten
>  Password = 1982
>
>  1982 was the release year of E.T.

FYI only one person can be logged in, so someone please extract the data and put it in an answer... :)

Comment: Haha! I didn't had that anywhere in my mind :D +1

Comment: @Techidiot See my edit please.

Comment: And I am out. Go for it. Still amused about this step..

Comment: @Techidiot I'm on my phone.  I'm not the man for the job :)

Comment: Okay. Let me quickly grab it then.

Comment: How interesting :)

Comment: [narration addedum] Just before I left Steven's computer, I noticed the popping sound of an incoming mail.

Comment: @LilianDelaveau I figured that but I haven't figured out which type it is... ;)

Comment: @LilianDelaveau Don't rush the puzzle.  Let it work :)

Comment: @LeppyR64 I hesitated before doing that move, but there was a mistake on my side, some elements should have been there from the start and sadly weren't. Thanks for your remark, though, as I am actively learning how to make puzzles better.

Comment: @LilianDelaveau Cheers.  I'm a usual solver of this type of puzzle.  I understand.  You've done a good job with this one so far and hopefully I can get home to a computer to do this next step sometime.  I'm pretty sure I know what it is, but the characterset doesn't look right to me.